# Can angular ui popover title be an angular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am not able to set popover-html to an angular expression.

For eg
The angular markup

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="something.html">
   <button>dummy</button>
</script>
<button popover-is-open="sm.isOpen" 
popover-template="'something.html'" 
popover-placement="top" popover-title="sm.popoverTitle"/>
```

The controller code

```
 function activate(){
      $scope.sm={};
      $scope.sm.isOpen=true;
      $scope.sm.popoverTitle=" Functionality  <button>close</button>";
 }
 activate();
```

The popover title renders as 'sm.popoverTitle' instead of the html markup i specified.

I am using angular UI Bootstrap version 0.13.4

Comment: Have you tried enclosing it in brackets? {{sm.popoverTitle}}

Comment: You are a friggin genius!!! Please add as answer so i can accept. This thing is so messed up. The popover-is-open doesnt have to be inclosed in {} but popover-title does. Looks like inconsistency bordering on being a bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the title in brackets so angular knows to fetch the content.

```
<button popover-is-open="sm.isOpen" 
    popover-template="'something.html'" 
    popover-placement="top" popover-title="{{sm.popoverTitle}}"/>
```